"But" negating "nots"
Stumbled on the following sentence in the "A Christmas Carol" book:

Not a latent echo in the house, not a squeak and scuffle from the mice
behind the panelling, not a drip from the half-thawed water-spout in
the dull yard behind, not a sigh among the leafless boughs of one
despondent poplar, not the idle swinging of an empty store-house door,
no, not a clicking in the fire, but fell upon the heart of Scrooge
with a softening influence, and gave a freer passage to his tears

As I understand this sentence, it can be rewritten (roughly) as follows:

a latent echo in the house, a squeak and scuffle from the mice behind
the panelling, a drip from the half-thawed water-spout in the dull
yard behind, a sigh among the leafless boughs of one despondent
poplar,  the idle swinging of an empty store-house door, yes, even a
clicking in the fire, all fell upon the heart of Scrooge with a
softening influence, and gave a freer passage to his tears

So "but fell" somehow negates every "not" preceding it. Could you please explain how does it happen and provide some more examples so I could finally understand how this construction works?

'A Christmas Carol' was published in 1843. You have found a very old-fashioned use of 'but', where that word isn't negating; rather, it's highlighting the exception. It's literally being used as a synonym for 'except' or 'other than.' No one passed by but smiled at my sister (everyone who passed by smiled at her).

"There was not a latent echo (or all the other things mentioned) that did not fall on Scrooge's heart with a softening influence..."

Not one X but (it) {verb phrase}...

There was not one pen in the drawer but it was out of ink.

Every pen in the drawer was out of ink.

I went to the used bookstore looking for a copy of A Christmas Carol. There was not one copy but it had some writing in the margins.

Every copy of A Christmas Carol in the bookstore had been annotated by a previous owner.
P.S. For every X, {verb phrase} resolved to true. "Not one but"  means there were no exceptions to {verb phrase}.
Every pen, without exception, was out of ink.  Every copy, without exception, had been annotated by a former owner.
